# Meaning of last values in test sampling

Tags: dataframe, if-statement, logistic-regression, prediction

`data.test_1$pred <- ifelse(data.test_1$score<=cut_off, 0, 1)`

I am trying to get the predictions from my test sampling. Since I am running this code I would like to know the meaning of the last values in the code "[...], 0, 1)" stands for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data.test_1$pred <- ifelse(data.test_1$score<=cut_off, 0, 1)
```

If `data.test_1$score` is less than or equal to the `cut_off` value then return `0` else return `1`